# googleapis in Vue.js: TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-sheets, google-api

I'm trying to get some rows in a Google Spreadsheet with the googleapis for a Vue project and I've already created a project and the right service account credentials in the Google console.
The problem is that I get this error when I click the button: `TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function` but I'm using this simple code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <button class="button" @click="getData">Get data</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',

  methods: {
    getData: async function() {
      const { google } = require('googleapis');
      const range = 'Data!A2:C999';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I can't understand what causes this error, it appears that something is wrong in `const { google } = require('googleapis');` but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after applying the workaround [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1775) the problem is solved.

It seems there is a problem running readFile() on the browser.

What you need to do is edit your webpack.config.js file like this

```
module.exports = {
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    alias: {
        fs: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/mock-fs.js')
    }
  }
};
```

If you are using Vue CLI 3 then you need to create a vue.config.js file at the root level, since there is no webpack.config.js file created when you create the project (it is created at the runtime) and modify it like this [(more info)](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration)

```
module.exports = {
configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
        alias: {
            fs: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/mock-fs.js')
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Where mock-fs.js is

```
module.exports = {
readFile () {}
}
```

Comment: this works for me.  thank you!  this is very obscure.  do you know why making a separate file mock-fs.js work?

Answer (score 0):

`const { google } = require('googleapis');` is not the correct syntax.

You should instead add:

`import { google } from 'googleapis';`

below the opening `script` tag

Comment: Thanks but it did not solve the problem: Uncaught TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function

Comment: The error goes away if you don't try to import `googleapis`?

Comment: It worked perfectly fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-bartik-zqqmx

Comment: Yes the error goes away if i don't import googleapis, but even if I import it as you described the error seems to persist

Comment: And you have properly installed the dependency?

Comment: I did " npm i googleapis" and ""googleapis": "^46.0.0" appears in my package.json