# VueJS @google-cloud/logging-winston TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, logging, winston, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to add **@google-cloud/logging-winston** to my VueJS project.  I followed these https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging-winston and https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/samples/logging-winston-quickstart very closely.

I am getting `"TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function"`

How can this line `const {LoggingWinston} = require('@google-cloud/logging-winston')` cause the issue?  This line is directly from the documentation.  Any advice or solutions?

```
const winston = require('winston');

// error here:
const {LoggingWinston} = require('@google-cloud/logging-winston');
// code does not pass any further


const gcloudWinston = new LoggingWinston();

const logConfiguration = {
    format: winston.format.json(),
    'transports': [
        new winston.transports.Console(),
        // Add Cloud Logging
        gcloudWinston,
    ]
};

const logger = winston.createLogger(logConfiguration);

export default { logger }
```

Comment: I found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61599733/1465656

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Github](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1775) link by @bcoe try adding the following to your webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    alias: {
        fs: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/mock-fs.js')
    }
  }
};
```

Also mentioned in the [document](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration):

> If you need conditional behavior based on the environment, or want to
> directly mutate the config, use a function (which will be lazy
> evaluated after the env variables are set). The function receives the
> resolved config as the argument. Inside the function, you can either
> mutate the config directly, OR return an object which will be merged.

Refer to the code:

```
    // vue.config.js
    module.exports = {
      configureWebpack: config => {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
          // mutate config for production...
        } else {
          // mutate for development...
        }
      }

}
```